# Django REST Throttling with Redis

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, redis, throttling

I noticed in multiple threads that we need to use a better cache like 'Redis' instead of Django's default "LocMemCache' especially in production.

I have multiple settings files including
`base.py` and `master.py`

I have added my Redis Cache in the `base.py` as shown in the following snippet:

```
CACHES = {
    "alternate": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "DB": 1,
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "redis_cache.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

I intentionally made it alternate as I don't want to change caching across my application.

Not in my custom throttle I have the following implementation:

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle
from myproject.settings.base import CACHES

class CustomThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'custom_throttle'
    cache = CACHES['alternate']
```

The throttling rate is present in the same `base.py` file

However, when I run the request to that endpoint, I encounter the following error.

```
line 26, in throttle_success
    self.cache.set(self.key, self.history, self.duration)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'set'
```

I understand that I have to override throttle_success in this case, but I'm not sure what to change exactly.
Help?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's an issue with your configuration, your settings should have default cache as well.

```
CACHES = {
    "alternate": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "DB": 1,
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "redis_cache.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    },
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "DB": 2,
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "redis_cache.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have defined settings like this, you should update CustomThrottle with a cache object, not a CACHE setting.

```
from django.core.cache import caches
class CustomThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'custom_throttle'
    cache = caches['alternate']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Will try it out